# IE developer tools cant debug Angular JS page?

Tags: internet-explorer

I have an Angular JS app. The page is working fine in IE but I want to use the developer tools. When I look at the html in the developer tools I can see that its just showing the loading page. So it looks like the tools dont update when the page does with javascript.

How can I debug the page? Ive had this issue before with IE dev tools not seeing content created with javascript. Last time I simply made sure the dev tools were open when I refreshed the page which fixed it, but thats not solving it this time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you may be using an older version of Internet Explorer, which would require manual refreshes for an updated DOM view in the Developer Tools. The button for refreshing the DOM was located in the top-left of the tools.

Modern versions of Internet Explorer [will auto-update](http://twitpic.com/earknb) the DOM Explorer on changes.